# Starting Flume Agent from Java Application

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I have written a Java application which builds flume config files and writes them to disk on a Linux box. The application then builds the flume commands and attempts to start the flume agent by running the command in the following code:

```
  try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(flumeStartCommand.toString());
                    p.waitFor(); 
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
```

If I take the flume command and execute it manually through the terminal, it works fine. When the java application attempts to execute the flume command, nothing happens. Is this a classpath issue?

Flume Command here:
/root/flume-flume-1.6/flume-ng-dist/target/apache-flume-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/apache-flume-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/bin/flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file /root/flumeconfs/ConsumerGroup4.conf --name Agent_ConsumerGroup4 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -Dflume.monitoring.type=http -Dflume.monitoring.port=34548

I know that embedded agents are another option but these are only available for an avro sink which is not very useful for me. Appreciate any thoughts.
Cheers,
Colman

Comment: u can put that in script and call that script in java

Comment: yup I've tried doing this too. Creating a script called flume.sh with the first line starting a bash shell and the second line executing the above query. Still doesn't start the agent, just hangs...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to figure this out, the flume command needs to be broken up into parameters in a String array as below:

```
String[] flumeCommand = new String[]{"/root/flume-flume-1.6/flume-ng-dist/target/apache-flume-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/apache-flume-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/bin/flume-ng",
                                   "agent",
                                   "--conf",
                                   "conf",
                                   "--conf-file",
                                   _flumeConfigurationDir+Active.getFlumeConfName(),
                                   "--name",
                                   Active.getFlumeAgentName(),
                                   "-Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console",
                                   "-Dflume.monitoring.type=http",
                                   "-Dflume.monitoring.port="+Active.getFlumeMetricsPort(),
};
```

Then use the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder flumeCommandBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(flumeCommand);
File flumeConfigurationDirFile = new File(_flumeConfigurationDir);
flumeCommandBuilder.directory(flumeConfigurationDirFile);                       
System.out.println("Working Directory: "+ flumeCommandBuilder.directory());
flumeCommandBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = flumeCommandBuilder.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("tasklist: " + line);
```

Comment: @ColmanWhat if I want to execute this command on a remote flume host rather than local machine?